# htaccess redirecting for this conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect users to particular if page url contains mountain view like this

`www.sitename.com/mountain%20view.htm` 
to
`www.sitename.com/hyderabad.htm`

i tried this but it's not working.

```
Redirect ^Mountain%20View.htm http://www.sitename.com/hyderabad.htm?location=hyderabad
```

similarly i want to redirect

`www.sitename.com/mountain%20view/anything` to `www.sitename.com/hyderabad/anything`

How to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You should `RedirectMatch` to get regex support:

```
RedirectMatch 302 "^/Mountain( |\x20)View\.htm$" /hyderabad.htm?location=hyderabad
```